# What is the difference between atLeastOnce and times(1) in mockito?

Tags: java, mockito, verify

In unit test using Mockito framework, I wanted to check whether someMethod is called or not.

I used verify() with atLeastOnce().someMethod(), debugger showed that someMethod() is not called and threw a `NullPointerException`.

However, when I changed atLeastOnce() to times(1) , the test passed.
What is the difference between these two?

Comment: `atLeastOnce()` is `>= 1`. `times(1)` is `== 1`. Could you please show your actual code? Both `atLeastOnce()` and `times()` return a `VerificationMode` which does not have a `someMethod()` method

Comment: FYI, it should be `verify(mock, times(1)).someMethod()` / `verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod()`. Note that `someMethod()` is called on the return value of `verify()`

Comment: A Mockito verification failure won't give you a NullPointerException.  There must be some other difference here.  Can you show us the code that throws the exception?

Comment: Any progress on that issue?